# When we ionise an atom and give it charge. Is conservation of charge violated there?

Tags: charge

In my coaching institute my teacher said that charge can neither be created nor be destroyed, But when ionise an atom and give it some charge (+ or -), there we are creating charge and my teacher also said that charge cannot be converted into energy but we do convert charge to mechanical energy in DC motor. Can you please help me with my problem I cannot find any solution to it, your help will help me a lot.

Answer (score 2):

When you ionize an atom it now has a positive charge, and a free electron is released from the atom, which has a negative charge. The total charge of the system is still zero.

In a motor it is not "charge" being turned into energy. It's electrical energy. The movement of charged particles is part of the explanation for how energy is released, but it isn't charge itself that is being turned into energy.

Comment: Ok sir, so sir does that mean they are talking about the whole system in conservation of charge?

Comment: Yes indeed the entire universe's charge doesn't change. Not just one single atom. By hitting a metal with high energy x-rays, you can make a new positron (+1) and electron (-1 charge)

Answer (score -2):

Your teacher is right. Large is always preserved, but a + and a- charge can combine and you have nor charge as result. Making Ions you can either split a molecule in two Ions one positiv, one negative,  or you can add a electron to an molecule or atom  to get a negative ion or take away an electron to get a positive ion
2.In a motor, charge travels through the wires and you get the energy, but the charge is conserved, like when you use  running water to doge a mill working, you do not loose water, but the water looses energy, like the charges in the wire.

Comment: Thank you so much sir for such a great explanation

Comment: *Large is always preserved.* Please fix this typo. I can’t fix it for you, because it is too small an edit for the system to accept.

Comment: What does *"doge a mill working"* mean?